# SQL Server Error Expected 1 export(s) with contract name Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

When I try to query data in SSMS v17.3, I get the following error message:

> Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints. (mscorlib)

I have Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 Community Editions on my machine.

What I have tried:

- Deleted any `ComponentCache` folders from `AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio`
- Repaired SSMS and rebooted

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a query that you tried to execute :)

Answer (score 7):

For SSMS 2018, Delete the **ComponentModelCache** from the following path 
 **\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell**
 For other versions find **ComponentModelCache** folder from  **"%AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\"** path and delete it.

Comment: I had the same error but found `ComponentModelCache` in the folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell`. Deleting it there fixed the error for me. This is for SSMS v18.8.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - the second part of this resolved it for me - change the version # to your version - found on another site

Based on your description, I’m sensing that the issue is with Visual Studio Isolated shell. If you are getting this error in SSMS 2016, I would suggest you delete or rename the ComponentModelCache folder under ”%AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\” and ”%AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0\" see if the issue goes away.

If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio gave me the following error: "Export operations (1) with the contract name "Microsoft internal Visual studio.PlattormUliSclutionAttachedCollectio nService2" are expected, but after applying the appropriate restrictions, 0 was found."
I could not solve this problem for a long time (the Internet did not help), but then I remembered that I had downloaded the proposed updates for Windows before that. This let me know that the updates may have affected the Visual Studio system. After reviewing the update log, I found "Cumulative Update.NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8.1..." and realized that this is the cause of the error. Therefore, in order for Visual Studio to work, I updated it. And only after that everything worked for me.

Comment: Please organize your answer into several paragraphs. It is very dense, and it took me a bit of effort to realize that the solution that your answer poses is to simply update Visual Studio. Perhaps you could leave a TLDR that recommends updating Visual Studio :)

Comment: Also, could you please specify how you reviewed the update log. What do you mean by "the update log"? As far as I know, there are many update log files.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-logs
Do you by chance mean that you ran the Get-WindowsUpdateLog cmdlet (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsupdate/get-windowsupdatelog?view=windowsserver2022-ps) in PowerShell?
:)